# Java Swing - Why JComponent won't display?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, extend, jcomponent

I'm trying to extend a class to eventually make a custom button.  I read in several places that it's best to extend as high as possible on the heirarchy (for better polymorphism?), so I'm trying to extend `JComponent`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestButton extends JComponent {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    
    public TestButton() {
        super();        
    }
    
}
```

And the code that calls this is:

```
 b1 = new TestButton();     
 basePanel.add(b1,gbc);  // (gbc is GridBagConstraints object)
```

The thing is, my `JComponent` isn't displayed in my layout.  If I extend the class as `JButton`, it shows no problem.  What's the deal?

**Update:**

FYI, this is sort of a noob conceptual question, I'm far from proficient here obviously.

Here's a picture to describe.  The only thing changed is `extends ______`.

What should be happening is a purple-filled block, the same height as the yellow block on the bottom.

What is happening is a default sized block that has no background (the black is from the JFrame).

[image]

Comment: http://www.swingexplorer.com/ is a good tool to use when debugging issues like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a blank component (basically a template). It has no properties. You have to add your own graphical elements by overriding the paintComponent method and then add logical elements by overriding the update method.

Comment: Ahhh ok.  So will a JComponent fill a gridbag cell automatically? (...provided the constraints are set to BOTH.) What makes an object have that fill behavior?

Comment: Agree with trashgod -- recommending the override of update in Swing is misguided. -1

Answer (score 4):

One of the main differences between `JComponent` and it's subclasses is that the latter have UI delegates, while `JComponent` does not. Note that the [`setBackground()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBackground%28java.awt.Color%29) "color is used only if the component is opaque, and only by subclasses of `JComponent` or `ComponentUI` implementations." As a result, you "must override `paintComponent()` to honor this property."

Comment: +1 Cheers that's half of the mystery, quite clear.  Any reason it's not filling up its gridbag cell?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the `GridBagLayout` guy, but I'm guessing something in the `PanelUI` for your chosen L&F. An [sscce](http://sscce.org/) might shed light.

Answer (score 3):

What do you expect to see in the place where `JComponent` is supposed to be? when you extend `JButton`, you get all its graphic with it, but you created an empty component, with nothing in it. Try putting something in the component (such as a `JLabel` or similar)

Comment: What I expected was a blocked-out area similar to JPanel, where I could set a background and stick stuff into it, but apparently that's not the case :)  Thanks for the tip, sounds good to me - I'll hit the code, back in a few.

Comment: OK, put a button in, but not the expected results (hard to explain).  Will a JComponent fill a gridbag cell automatically?  (The constraints are set to `BOTH`.)

Answer (score 3):

You still need to extends `JButton` if you want `JButton`'s functionality. Otherwise everybody can extend `Object` and expect everything.

Comment: I don't necessarily want JButton (yet), I just want a block with a background to fill my layout cell...the JComponent has a `setBackground` method already...

Answer (score 0):

Either use the JButton as it is:

```
 JButton b1 = new JButton("Enter JButton text here");     
 basePanel.add(b1,gbc);
```

or extend the JButton class if you wish to change certain properties and customize it for your own preferences:

```
public class TestButton extends JButton {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public TestButton(String buttonText) 
    {
        super(buttonText);        
    }

}
```